# How can i make Ken Burns effect with animation nodes?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, 2d

I have a camera and an image in the scene.
I would like to achieve random [Ken Burns effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Burns_effect) on the image with animation node with the constraint that the image will always stay inside the frame never showing the background.

I have achieved a simple [Ken Burns effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Burns_effect) where the image is zoomed and translated in only one direction. I would like to set a duration and then the animation node would navigate the image.

For example the duration would be 15s:  [0,3] the image scale and translate in one direction, [3,10] the image scale and translate in another direction and so on.

Thanks.